# `notification-daemon` completely absent although libnotify installed

Tags: debian, d-bus, libnotify

I'm running on x86_64 Debian 4.19 over i3-gaps & systemd; I'm interested in toying with the `org.freedesktop.Notifications` interface over the DBus, however there is no such service/interface/anything named as such whatsoever under `/usr/lib/dbus-1.0`, and no `/usr/lib/notification-daemon` nor `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notification-daemon`.

I've tried to recompile `libnotify` from source (including running `apt get libnotify-dev`) and still yet to no avail, I'm completely confused by where this daemon could be found and how I could generate the DBus services that should be there.

Remarkably enough when I run `notify-send`, there does show a notification box, and through `dbus-monitor` you can see:

```
method call time=1565902191.045580 sender=:1.130 -> destination=:1.131 serial=7 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
   string "notify-send"
   uint32 0
   string ""
   string "smh"
   string ""
   array [
   ]
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "urgency"
         variant             byte 2
      )
   ]
   int32 -1
method return time=1565902191.046365 sender=:1.131 -> destination=:1.130 serial=4 reply_serial=7
   uint32 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification daemon is available in its own package, `notification-daemon`.